# Alternative to Apache Tiles in pure HTML solution

Tags: web-apps, web-development, html

I am a Java Developer and always use Apache Tiles or Sitemesh to generate the template in Java Web Project, but in pure Html, Css & Javascript project.

What I can use?

Features

- Free is better than comercial
- Generate at least 1 placeholder like content
- No iframe solution